# cant run my project

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have these errors, can you help me?

> Warning:  include(/opt/lampp/htdocs/bookAppoint/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/bookAppoint/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/opt/lampp/htdocs/bookAppoint/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/bookAppoint/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269

Comment: Please elaborate and add required information in your question. What are you trying to acheieve, whats being done to solve this and all other vital information....

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in your codeigniter project folder in **index.php** file replace the **$application_folder** path.

**Replace with :**

$application_folder = getcwd().'/../application';